# Testing if points on a line are over/under dispersed

Tags: hypothesis-testing, monte-carlo, spatial, poisson-process, rayleigh-distribution

I have a series of about 1000 points on a chromosome and I want to know if they are clumped, over-dispersed, or neither.  The chromosome can be viewed as a 1-dimensional.

I've looked over [some spatial stats](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~ese502/NOTEBOOK/Part_I/3_Testing_Spatial_Randomness.pdf) and found 2 methods that look promising.

First one can chop the line into M segments, and the number of points in each segment should be Poisson distributed with λ = N/M, where N is the total number of points. Then it isn't too hard to construct a chi-squared test, where the observed is the point count in each segment, and the expected is λ.  The issue here of course is how to choose M.  I guess you try a range of values and see how stable the result is.

The second method is to compute the distance to the nearest neighbor (NN) for each point. The NN values are said to be Rayleigh distributed. I'm not very comfortable with this distribution and I'm struggling to construct a good test statistic for the NN values. Similarly, it would be easy to simulate a null distribution though Monte Carlo methods, but I'm not sure what the appropriate summary statistic is to compare my observed distribution against (maybe the variance?). Any help appreciated!

Comment: [Ripley's K](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~pcaragea/S40608/Notes/Dixon_Ripley_K.pdf) is popular metric, and is straightforward to apply in only one dimension (if its already available in your statistical software of choice for spatial point patterns you can simply pretend one of the dimensions is a constant). Quadrat stats can be underpowered (and ad-hoc). For nearest neighbor distances there are alot of different global tests, I would suggest checking out the [`spatstat` R package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spatstat/index.html) and all of the available tests.